# middleware is an object instead of a function

Tags: node.js, multer, gridfs

I'm trying to make a file upload API using multer gridFS, I used the documentation but I'm missing something:

this is my code:

```
const config = require("config");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const dbURI = config.get("mongoURI");
const multer = require("multer");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const path = require("path");
const GridFsStorage = require("multer-gridfs-storage");


var storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: dbURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: "uploads"
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

router.post("/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  res.json({ msg: "file uploaded successfully" });
});
```

I get an error  TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object which basically tells me that upload.single is not a function, what is my error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake, I was missing module.exports = router;